# Mobile number validation using semantic UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui, phone-number

I am using semantic UI. I have mobile number filed on the form. Validation is not working in the mobile field. I have to display the validation message "Enter the valid mobile number".

I know using Jquery validation but I have to use semantic UI.

Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Would you help me out with this issue?

```js
$('.ui.form').form({
    mobileno: {
      identifier  : 'mobileno',
      rules: [
        {
          type   : 'empty',
          prompt : 'Enter your mobile number'
        },{
            type   : 'minLength[10]',
            prompt : 'Please enter the valid mobile number'
          }
      ]
    }
  });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://oss.maxcdn.com/semantic-ui/2.1.4/semantic.min.css">

 <form action="process.php" method="post" class="ui form segment">
 <div class="field">
      <div class="ui input">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Contact number" name="mobileno">
   </div>
      </div>
      
      <input class="ui black submit button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/semantic-ui/2.1.4/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me out in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The script misses `fields: {...}` around the 'mobileno' element.

Also make sure that `$('.ui.form')` appears after the `jquery-3.1.1.min.js` import.

**Other JS imports may also interfere** with Semantic UI validation. Fox example, if you import 'jquery-ui.min.js' **after** 'semantic.min.js' it will break the validation (the 'error' style will not be appended to the invalid field).

Comment: thanks for the reply, after 5 months I got a reply. hahahhaha,   Can you help me with code?